# SSIS: FTP task - concurrent connections

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, ssis, ftp, connection

I have created an SSIS package for downloading file from FTP server.
When I debug the package, everything goes fine. But when I shedule the package as Job step, it sometimes fails to connect.
The job is sheduled to repeat every 4 hours and **in average every other run fails** with Error: *0xC002918F - The Login request was denied*.

**The connection is anonymous and doesn't require password**

I have tested it for a few hours now and found out some info:

- When tested in FileZilla, I found out that the server denies second connection trying to download a file. **Setting maximal number of concurrent connections to 1 got it working in FileZilla**
- FTP command in command line works fine. Maybe because it closes connection after every successful command
- In FTP connection manager, I didn't found the option to limit number of connections

I have no possibility to see the settings of the FTP server.
What confuses me the most is the fact, that some sheduled tasks work fine and some fail. I haven't found any regularity in it.

**What I have tried so far:**

- Active/pasive mode
- Limiting retries in FTP connection manager to 1
- Shifting the shedule time, so it doesn't collide with any other (older) tasks trying to download from the server
- Setting the FTP task to ASCII mode (The server says to FileZilla, that it only accepts ASCII characters)

No luck so far. Still some attemps success and some not.

**EDIT:**

The FTP server is on Simatic device.

For this week, i kept shedule for every 1 hour and kept pinging the device every 30 seconds. Still some SSID attempts don't succeed and ping goes through every time :-/

Comment: I've also tried adjusting the chunk size to no avail.

Comment: could you please check package Protection level property? please set protection level property as 'Rely on server storage and roles for access control'.

Comment: @Jacks, I don't have that option as it's hosted in the SSIS Catalog

Comment: @MattiPrice logs from SSIS would be beneficial.

Comment: @MattiPrice Could you please let me know about procedure how do you debug SSIS package?

Comment: @BryanSwan: Basic setup in SSIS is a for-each loop with an FTP task inside followed by a delete task. 5-10 files transfer successfully, then one errors. The logs show the last delete task completing, then the error message: "FTP Task: Error: An error occurred in the requested FTP operation. Detailed error description: The connection with the server was reset". What is truly odd is that it seems to run from my local machine just fine and never encounters the error. I'm trying to find if there's a difference in SSIS versions now.

Comment: @MattiPrice is there anything abnormal about this last file (size / format / location) and is this file consistently the one which causes the error? 'Sometimes' error, what percent? If this file is always the issue, can you have a separate task simply for this other file? Try this http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/08/foreach-ftp-file-enumerator.html

Comment: @BryanSwan, nope, nothing unusual, and it sends properly when you restart the job.

Answer (score 4):

I would replace the standard SSIS FTP Task with an Execute Process Task, and call WinSCP.

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation

I've found WinSCP is much more reliable and flexible. You can pass it a command line built using expressions to cover all the functionality of the SSIS FTP task, and more.

Comment: Part of the reason to use the FTP task in my case was to be able to delete the files after they were sent successfully. I might try this but I'm worried it may not solve the problem I'm having because I don't know if it's due to multiple logins at the same time or just opening and closing so many connections in quick succession.

Comment: Well that might be exactly what I was looking for then. I'll have to check that out.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to accept just using a workaround in this scenario, maybe set the SQL agent SSIS job step to retry after an X seconds delay (advanced tab of SQL job step). We do this a lot when connecting to flaky cloud API's with SSIS.

Or maybe a for loop container in your package which continues on failure & breaks out on success - maybe try 3 times to connect?

Sorry if this is all obvious to you already.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've set the job to run every hour and the require is to have data max 4 hours old. The job succeeds in 50% of attempts, so it is sufficient. I'm keeping this question active if somebody can solve the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Formerly the error was known as:

> '0xC002918F',-1073573489,'DTS_E_FTPTASK_UNABLETOCONNECTTOSERVER','Unable to connect to FTP server using "__".'

The FTP Task explicitly closes the connection at the end of action execution, so if the connection stays open it must be something with your server.

- Set the FTP Connection UsePassiveMode property to True by checking
  the appropriate checkbox in the FTP connection properties dialog box.
- Or http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/08/foreach-ftp-file-enumerator.html

Both [CozyRock](http://www.cozyroc.com/) and [PragmaticWorks](http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/Task-Factory) have fantastic FTP tasks for SSIS.

**Guidance listed on Microsoft's website**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/925880

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb794745.aspx

Aside from **firewall/permissions/restrictions** Check FTP credentials or to be exact how they saved/retrieved. The rule of thumb in that case is to rely on SQL Server, i.e. to use **"Rely on server storage and roles for access control" package protection level.** This approach should remove all FTP credentials problems altogether (excluding mistypos of course).

**However**, This is the default setting applied when using [Project Deployment Model to store packages in the SSISDB catalog which is where the package you noted resides.](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/ssis-2012-implementing-package-security-using-access-control.html)

Do not use XP_CMDSHELL and call external programs without a business necessity as the above poster advises. Enabling CMDSHELL is a significant security risk.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, sometimes `FILE LOCK` and `DB CONNECTION` do not terminate even after ending the package execution.

I suggest you use `Script Task` and do the upload using C# code and make sure you close the FTP connection at the end.

Comment: or use filezilla from a script task where you can control the timeout and automatic retries etc.  The point being that you are not relying on the built in ftp object in SSIS.  Like Mike Honey suggests below.

Comment: I just like to avoid using external executable as much as I can ;)

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, would you mind trying to update the package and set DelayValidation=True?

[image: DelayValidation: True]

Validation routines establish connections to test them.  Perhaps the validation routine is the other concurrent connection?  Worth a shot?

Comment: Tried this, didn't work for me but good thought. I don't seem to have issues when running it locally, but when deployed to a server that hosts it and runs it on a schedule, it seems to get through a couple files than break. My issue may be a little different than the OP's but the connections overlapping seems to be the root cause.